# Could somebody please help me understand how the following equation was derived from the original?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The following equation occurs in my physics textbook, with an equals mark showing a "simplified version" of the same equation. No matter what I do, I cannot see how this was derived. Can somebody please help out?

$\dfrac{q·r}{(R^2 + r^2)^{3/2}}$ = $\dfrac{q\cos^3Θ}{r^2}$

It says somewhere earlier on the same page that $\cosΘ=\dfrac{r}{(R^2+r^2)^{1/2}}$.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

If
$$\cos\Theta=\frac{r}{(R^2+r^2)^{1/2}}$$
then
$$\cos^3\Theta=\frac{r^3}{(R^2+r^2)^{3/2}}$$
and
$$\frac{q \cos^3\Theta}{r^2}=\frac{qr}{(R^2+r^2)^{3/2}}.$$